# Think Python (How to think like a computer scientist) - Excercise 8.4 Duckling question

Tags: python

I have an additional question related to the link below:

[Think Python (How to think like a computer scientist) - Excercise 8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239330/think-python-how-to-think-like-a-computer-scientist-excercise-8-4)

I tried using this method to produce a solution to the ducklings problem, but it's not producing the answer I wanted. I wish to know what is wrong with my code because I can't seem to figure it out :(

[image]

as you can see, I think I set the conditions right : when the letter is O or Q, you add 'u' between the prefix and suffix, and you print everything else the way it was. But the thing is, the output is adding 'u' to everything, not just O or Q.

Is there some kind of syntax error I did wrong? I'm having a hard time trying to understand what I did wrong and I would appreciate it if anyone could point out my mistake and how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if letter == 'O' or 'Q':
```

does *not* do what you think it does (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for operator precedence), it's equivalent to:

```
if (letter == 'O') or ('Q'):
```

---

And, since `'Q'` is a truthy value, the condition of that `if` statement is *always* true. What you would need in your case would be:

```
if letter == 'O' or letter == 'Q':
```

but a more Pythonic way would be:

```
if letter in ['O', 'Q']:
```

This also better matches your original thinking where you want to detect if the letter is any of a certain group of letters, rather than explicitly checking the letter against each and every one.

Answer (score 0):

here, `if letter =='O' or 'Q'` is read as `if (letter=='O') or 'Q'` .

ie it check, that value of letter is `O` or not. and using `or` operations.
so when `Letter=='O'` is True and `Q` is always True.

so in `OR` operation `True&True=True`, `True&False=True` , `False&True=True` and `False&False=False`.

so since `Q` will be always True, hence the condition `if letter=='O' or 'Q'` will be always true and next statement `print(letter+'u'+suffix)` always executed.

to avoid this, you just also need to check if `letter=='Q'` or not.This will help you to get True or False when Letter is `Q` or not.

so change the code to `if letter == 'O' or letter =='Q'`